# Rendering with jquery and locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Im having trouble rendering with jquery, I have a notification page which shows all notifications, then when i click on 1 for example it will show all the 1's and if i click 2 it will show all the 2's etc etc.

This is where all the notifications are rendered to start with. The locals work fine here.

```
<% @notifications.each do |x| %>
  <div class="testing123">
    <%= render 'notification', x: x %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then i click the link to change them
and here is the controller

```
def index
  if params[:type]
    @notifications = Notification.where(notification_type: params[:type])
  else
    @notifications = Notification.all
  end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js{
        render 'notifications/jserb/select_notifications'
      }
  end
end
```

Which then arrives here:

```
$('.testing123').empty();
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @notifications, :locals => {:x => x}) %>").appendTo(".testing123");
```

But i keep getting this error
 `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method x' for #<#<Class:0x007fae10882ed8>:0x007fae0f6234b8>):`

EDIT-1: here is where i click the link:

```
<%= link_to "likes", notifications_path, remote: true %>
```

EDIT-2: here is the notification:

```
<div class="notification-body flerowspb" id="body<%=x.id%>">
  <div class="flerowspb" style="width:80%">
    <div class="notif-check flecolcen">
      <%= check_box_tag "read_notif[]", value="#{x.id}", checked = false, options = {class: 'checked-id', id: "check-#{x.id}"} %>
    </div>
    <div class="notif-details ">
      <div class="notif-time flerowspb">
        <% if !x.viewed %>
           <span class="glow" id="glow-<%=x.id%>"> New  <%= x.notification_type.capitalize %></span>
        <% else %>
           <span><span class="text-grey"> New <%= x.notification_type.capitalize %></span></span>
         <% end %>
         <span class="text-grey font-small"> <%= time_ago_in_words(x.created_at) %> ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="notif-body font-medium text-grey">
        You have <%= x.status_count %> <%= x.title %>  <br>
        Click <span class="text-blue"><%= link_to "Here", entry_path(x.entry_id, notification_id: x.id) %> </span> to view it
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notif-image">
    <%= image_tag x.entry.image.small_thumb %>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT-3: here is the full error that i get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `x' for #<#<Class:0x007fae0e6f32b8>:0x007fae11ac1838>):
1: <div class="notification-body flerowspb" id="body<%=x.id%>">
2:   <div class="flerowspb" style="width:80%">
3:     <div class="notif-check flecolcen">
4:       <%= check_box_tag "read_notif[]", value="#{x.id}", checked = false, options = {class: 'checked-id', id: "check-#{x.id}"} %>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `respond_to do |format|` should be handled both if and else cases. Right now it handling js requests in else case only

Comment: how do u request to change it ? Can you post that code where u click it. Its supposed to be script request to get js render.

Comment: Added remote: true to the link? Also pull the `respond_to do |format|` out side of else block. So it will work if there is params[:type]

Comment: @7urkm3n ok ive edited the respond_to code and added in the link which i click

Comment: @johnseymour You have 2  x s. Out of which one is for the yield of .each block. what is another one for?

Comment: @AkashPinnaka Not quite sure i understand? but ive added in the code that it renders. Hope thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your code is after click on link it hits the notifications action and where you are getting `@notifications` as array of notifications, so after this in your `js.erb` you are rendering appending partial `notification.html.erb` with local variable `x` but here at your controller you are getting `@notifications` variable,

This should be like: 
in `notifications/_notification.html.erb`

```
<div class="testing123">
  <% notifications.each do |x| %>
     <%#= render 'notification', x: x %>
     #...
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and in `notification.js.erb`

```
$('.testing123').empty();
$(".testing123").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'notifications/notification', notifications: @notifications) %>");
```

Comment: Sorry im little bit confused, so the <div class="testing123"> ... </div> needs to go into the _notification partial then what goes after `<%#= render 'notification', x: x %>` this line?

Comment: @john not sure what are trying to do but so far as I figured that you were rendering in js erb page with wrong variables. And I think you don't need to create another partial you can do that stuffs in notification partial instead of `<%#= render 'notification', x: x %> `  on other hand if you still need another partial to you can create another partial. But the concept of rendering appending parties in js erb page will remain same. Hopefully you get this, let me know for further guidance thanks.

Comment: I sat down and had a sandwich and walked through the process and worked it out! I see now i did have wrong variables. Thanks for helping me out!